# Typescript inference on custom undefined check

Tags: typescript

I can't imagine this question hasn't been asked already, but I can't find it. That may have something to do with not knowing what keywords to search for that describe my question.

Anyway, let's say we have this Typescript:

```js
const value = undefined
const doSomethingWithValue = (value: number) => console.log(value)
const isDefined = (value?: unknown) => value != null

if (value != null) {
  doSomethingWithValue(value) // Works great!
}

if (isDefined(value)) {
  doSomethingWithValue(value) // Boo, error!: Argument of type 'undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
}
```

As you can see, the `isDefined` function checks for `null`/`undefined`, but Typescript can't seem to figure it out like it does when using the explicit check in the `if` statement. I know I can add a type hint like so:

```js
if (isDefined(value)) {
  doSomethingWithValue(value as unknown as number) // Works, but "eh"
}
```

Which is okay, I suppose - definitely not ideal. Is there not a better way?

**EDIT: Non-null assertion operator**

So, I just learned I can use the "Non-null assertion operator" like so, but it's still not "great":

```js
if (isDefined(value)) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
  doSomethingWithValue(value!) // Works, not ideal still...
}
```

That works, but requires disabling the eslint rule `@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion`: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v5.1.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-non-null-assertion.md, where the docs warn: "Using non-null assertions cancels the benefits of the strict null-checking mode." and "If you don't care about strict null-checking, then you will not need this rule."

But, I do care about strict null checking! I don't want to disable that entirely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIrst of all:

```js
if (value != null) {
  doSomethingWithValue(value) // Works great!
}
```

It does not work great. `value` is infered as `never` and `never` is assignable to any type.

If you want to work with `value` and `isDefined`, you should convert `isDefined` into [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
declare const value: undefined | null | number;

const doSomethingWithValue = (value: number) => console.log(value)

const isDefined = <T,>(value: T | null | undefined):
  value is NonNullable<T> =>
  value != null && value !== undefined


if (isDefined(value)) {
  doSomethingWithValue(value) // ok
}

declare const value2: undefined | null | string;

if (isDefined(value2)) {
  value2 // string
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20211028#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABBA9gOwM4BdEDcZQCuYAXIoWuAGYCWaYIiAPomoVFM64QLYBGYOAG5gwVJhwgUAZRQ8wWABZ0A5gHUaSgGoFiiALyIAFPiKlu-QQEoDAPmToMKKGAB0UFCpO6wV0eOxEGgwAETBaekZDAB4AFQAaW28zMliuNg4uCmo6BisSYEQ8HyCMRAA5dHL2WD4XOPt9W0Lis0QAQkMMzgAyHta9TsNs8NyQURoqY1NBrpqbAG8WqVl5JVUNbR9k4hsAej3ENRQ4AGsylQQYLHbgAF8JqaNgsIiGHd9F5Zk5BWU0dSaRQ6MwffaHFCne6icDQeBIAI4GZgABMZBGb0YLG6XGwcFUImAk2ML1GkQ%20KKsXyKyJRiAOiDxqmhQA)

Comment: Sweet. Indeed, using a custom type guard solves this problem:

Comment: Not sure about the first part tho, and it doesn't really matter, but that totally works for me. `value` is not inferred as `never`.

And, as a side note, `value !== undefined` is redundant. `value != null` correctly checks for `undefined` since `undefined == null`